# How do I fix this file that has become partially hex?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, file-recovery, file-format, ubuntu-16.04

I had a Java file that was part of a project; it went missing after running `fsck`. I later found it in `/lost+found` but now it seems to be part-hex and part-text:

[image: Here is a picture]

How can I restore this to normal text?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and my file system is ext4.

Comment: You restore from a backup that you made.  That is likely the only reasonable way.  It looks like your computer failed to keep track of how to find all of the pieces of a file, and ended up mixing a piece of the file alongside data which was not part of that file.  The only other ways to fix are likely searching for content known to be part of the file, or manually, neither of which is likely easy (and both of which may be unfeasible to do reasonably).  (Of course, if this were super critical, some experts might be willing to invest in such extraordinary efforts.)

Comment: "it seems to be part-hex and part-text" - sorry that is the way the file is DISPLAYED, try `$ od -t x1z path_and_name_of_the_file` (from bash/terminal) for a more complete view of the content. TOOGAM's comment is still true though.

Comment: I don't think I made a backup. Ubuntu doesn't backup files automatically does it?